# How I can select rows from a dataframe that do not match?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to identify the values in a data frame that do not match, but can't figure out how to do this.

```
# make data frame 
a <- data.frame( x =  c(1,2,3,4)) 
b <- data.frame( y =  c(1,2,3,4,5,6))

# select only values from b that are not in 'a'
# attempt 1: 
results1 <- b$y[ !a$x ]

# attempt 2:  
results2 <- b[b$y != a$x,]
```

If `a = c(1,2,3)` this works, as `a` is a multiple of `b`. However, I'm trying to just select all the values from data frame `y`, that are not in `x`, and don't understand what function to use.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need the negation of the `%in%` operator. Something like this should work:

`subset(b, !(y %in% a$x))`

```
> subset(b, !(y %in% a$x))
  y
5 5
6 6
```

Comment: Thanks @Chase, I spend some time trying to figure out what the negation of the `%in%` operator was, but could not figure it out. This answer is also helpful as it neatly subsets the data.

Comment: @celenius - the `%in%` operator returns a logical vector that tells us whether or not there is a match between the first operator and the second. `(b$y %in% a$x) [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE`. The `!` implies negation so will return  `!(b$y %in% a$x)[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE ` . Does that help explain things?

Comment: Late to the party, but Hmisc now has a function `%nin%` which is not in. Very useful

Answer (score 28):

Try the set difference function `setdiff`. So you would have

```
results1 = setdiff(a$x, b$y)   # elements in a$x NOT in b$y
results2 = setdiff(b$y, a$x)   # elements in b$y NOT in a$x
```

Answer (score 26):

You could also use `dplyr` for this task. To find what is in `b` but not `a`:

```
library(dplyr)    
anti_join(b, a, by = c("y" = "x"))

#   y
# 1 5
# 2 6
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, never saw it before, thanks Joe (works with dbplyr i.e. in a SQL remote context)