# Opposite of %in%: exclude rows with values specified in a vector

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

A categorical variable V1 in a data frame D1 can have values represented by the letters from A to Z. I want to create a subset D2, which excludes some values, say, B, N and T. Basically, I want a command which is the opposite of `%in%`

```
D2 = subset(D1, V1 %in% c("B", "N", "T"))
```

Comment: not %in%? (`!(x %in% y)`). Life can be easy sometimes...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How I can select rows from a dataframe that do not match?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812478/how-i-can-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-that-do-not-match)

Answer (score 486, accepted):

You can use the `!` operator to basically make any TRUE FALSE and every FALSE TRUE. so:

```
D2 = subset(D1, !(V1 %in% c('B','N','T')))
```

EDIT:
You can also make an operator yourself:

```
'%!in%' <- function(x,y)!('%in%'(x,y))

c(1,3,11)%!in%1:10
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: The use of second option is illustrated in the help(match) page (where you would get to if you typed `?"%in%"` ) where the new operator is called `%w/o%`.

Comment: also, see `?Negate`
e.g. `"%ni%" <- Negate("%in%")`

Comment: Negate worked for me when used after defining the new operator, as suggested by baptiste, e.g. ``subset(df, variable %ni% c("A", "B"))`` , but not when used directly, e.g. ````subset(df, variable Negate("%in%") c("A", "B"))````

Comment: @PatrickT that’s because only operators can be used as operators. and operators are either built-in or start and end with `%`. To create an operator, you need to assign a function with two operands to a name starting and ending with `%`.

Comment: We can also use `filter(!(V1%in% c('B','N','T')))`.

Comment: Another option is to use `slice(-which(V1 %in% Vector))` if using a single vector (e.g., `Vector <- seq(from=1, to=10, by=2)`) instead of a matrix, dataframe, or tibble

Comment: To clarify my above comment, `slice()` is usually used to remove rows by row number instead of by column values

Answer (score 109):

How about:

```
`%ni%` <- Negate(`%in%`)
c(1,3,11) %ni% 1:10
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: this one actually doesn't work as it throws an error something about `SPECIAL` `%ni`

Comment: Still works just fine.  R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10) Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit) Running under: macOS Big Sur 10.16

Comment: its becuase `'` is not `\``, and you should use the `\``

Comment: The changes have been made. Thanks.

Answer (score 60):

Here is a version using `filter` in `dplyr` that applies the same technique as the accepted answer by negating the logical with !:

```
D2 <- D1 %>% dplyr::filter(!V1 %in% c('B','N','T'))
```

Answer (score 36):

If you look at the code of `%in%`

```
 function (x, table) match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) > 0L
```

then you should be able to write your version of opposite. I use

```
`%not in%` <- function (x, table) is.na(match(x, table, nomatch=NA_integer_))
```

Another way is:

```
function (x, table) match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) == 0L
```

Answer (score 17):

Using [`negate`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/negate.html) from [`purrr`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/) also does the trick quickly and neatly:

```
`%not_in%` <- purrr::negate(`%in%`)
```

Then usage is, for example,

```
c("cat", "dog") %not_in% c("dog", "mouse")
```

Comment: There’s also a built-in `Negate` that does the same. The only difference is that purrr calls `as_mapper` on the thing you pass, while `Negate` calls `match.fun`. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/purrr/versions/0.2.5/topics/as_mapper https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/match.fun.html

Answer (score 9):

`purrr::compose()` is another quick way to define this for later use, as in:

```
`%!in%` <- compose(`!`, `%in%`)
```

Answer (score 6):

Another solution could be using `setdiff`

```
D1 = c("A",..., "Z") ; D0 = c("B","N","T")

D2 = setdiff(D1, D0)
```

`D2` is your desired subset.

Comment: Sometimes it can be useful but it doesn't produce the same results if the are repetitions.

Answer (score 3):

```
library(roperators)

1 %ni% 2:10
```

If you frequently need to use custom infix operators, it is easier to just have them in a package rather than declaring the same exact functions over and over in each script or project.

Comment: While this may be a correct answer, it would be more useful with additional explanation of _why_ it works. Consider editing it to include further details, and if you feel it's better than the accepted answer which was posted nearly a decade ago.

Answer (score 3):

Hmisc has `%nin%` function, which should do this.

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Hmisc/versions/4.4-0/topics/%25nin%25

Answer (score 1):

The package [collapse](/questions/tagged/collapse) has it built in: `%!in%`.

Answer (score 0):

The help for %in%, `help("%in%")`, includes, in the Examples section, this definition of not in,

`"%w/o%" <- function(x, y) x[!x %in% y] #--  x without y`

Lets try it:

```
c(2,3,4) %w/o% c(2,8,9)
[1] 3 4
```

Alternatively

```
"%w/o%" <- function(x, y) !x %in% y #--  x without y
c(2,3,4) %w/o% c(2,8,9)
# [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require(TSDT)

c(1,3,11) %nin% 1:10
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

For more information, you can refer to: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TSDT/TSDT.pdf

Answer (score -2):

In Frank Harrell's package of R utility functions, he has a %nin% (not in) which does exactly what the original question asked. No need for wheel reinvention.