# What is the opposite of %in% in r

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Opposite of %in%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831794/opposite-of-in)

What is the opposite of

```
matrix[matrix%in%1,]?

!%in% does not work.
```

I would like to select items that do not contain a certain number.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You want:

```
matrix[!matrix %in% 1,]
```

For clarity's sake, I prefer this, even though the parentheses aren't necessary.

```
matrix[!(matrix %in% 1),]
```

Also note that you need to be aware of [FAQ 7.31: Why doesn't R think these numbers are equal?](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f).

Answer (score 33):

If you find yourself using @Joshua's suggestion often, you could easily make your own `%notin%` operator.

```
`%notin%` <- Negate(`%in%`)
'a' %notin% c('b', 'c')
# [1] TRUE
```