# Negation of %in% in R

Tags: r, match, negation

Is there a short negation of `%in%` in R like `!%in%` or `%!in%`?

---

Of course I can negate `c("A", "B") %in% c("B", "C")` by `!(c("A", "B") %in% c("B", "C"))` (cf. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831794/opposite-of-in)) but I would prefere a more straight forward approach and save a pair of brackets (alike presumably most people would prefer `c("A", "B") != c("B", "C")` over `!(c("A", "B") == c("B", "C"))`).

Comment: @SpencerCastro I included a link to the question you mentioned. My question is different: I'm aware of the technical possibilities on how to negate %in%. My question is about whether there is a strait forward approach or not. And the answer given by user "catastrophic-failure" saying "No, [...] but ..." was what I wanted to know.

Comment: Great, I think linking these questions is helpful, because both provide a full explanation of solutions.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

No, there isn't a built in function to do that, but you could easily code it yourself with

```r
`%nin%` = Negate(`%in%`)
```

Or

```r
`%!in%` = Negate(`%in%`)
```

---

See this thread and followup discussion: [%in% operator - NOT IN](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/in-operator-NOT-IN-td3506655.html) (alternatively [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-May/277498.html))

---

Also, it was pointed out the package `Hmisc` includes the operator `%nin%`, so if you're using it for your applications it's already there.

```
library(Hmisc)
"A" %nin% "B"
#[1] TRUE
"A" %nin% "A"
#FALSE
```

Comment: Curious why this function exists, given all it does is literally throw a `!` in front of its argument

Comment: ! as well as parentheses. it's a time saver. 1 key < 3 keys plus arrowing around to create parenthesis

Answer (score 11):

You can always create one:

```
> `%out%` <- function(a,b) ! a %in% b

> 1:10 %out% 5:15
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Otherwise there is a somewhat similar function with `setdiff`, which returns the **unique** elements of `a` that are not in `b`:

```
> setdiff(1:10,5:15)
[1] 1 2 3 4
> setdiff(5:15,1:10)
[1] 11 12 13 14 15
```

Comment: You (or rather, the OP) should be careful with using `setdiff` instead of a negated `%in%` since, as the name indicates, it's a _set_ operation and hence, only returns _unique_ elements of `a` that are not in `b`. That may be a very different result from a negated `%in%`.

Comment: True, i'll edit to make that point clearer. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Actually you don't need the extra parentheses, `!c("A", "B") %in% c("B", "C")` works.

If you prefer something that reads easier, just define it yourself:

```
"%nin%" <- function(x, table) match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) == 0L
```

This has the advantage of not wasting effort -- we don't get a result and then negate it, we just get the result directly. (the difference should generally be trivial)

Answer (score 4):

The    `%!in%` function is now available in the    `library(operators)`

Comment: I just tried using this from the operators package. The packages seemed to be causing issues with dplyr::group_by() I didn't debug it, but the issue went away once I removed the library call.