# splitting data using %in% and "%!in%"

Tags: r

I'd like to split the content of my data frame into two based on whether or not the data contain "ID" column values specified in a second list.

I have dplyr loaded and %in% below  works well, but get but %!in% returned the following error:

> D2a<-D1[D1$ID%in%modtab2$ID,]

```
> D2b<-D1[D1$ID%!in%modtab2$ID,]
> Error in lapply(x, `[`, i) : could not find function "%!in%"
```

Suggestions on a fix?

Comment: This is not a `dplyr` issue; I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831794/opposite-of-in) will help you.

Comment: if you want to use `dplyr` functions, try `inner_join()` and `anti_join()`

Answer (score 1):

As the error message said `%!in%` isn't a R function.

You have to negate the whole expression e.g. `!(x %in% y)`

So you can probably do : `D1[!(D1$ID %in% modtab2$ID), ]`

You can also create a custom `%!in%` function :

```
`%!in%` <- function(x, y) !(x %in% y)
```