# How to remove rows of datatable by specific values

Tags: r, data.table, subset

Sample Data:

```
DT = data.table(x=rep(c("b","a","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), v=1:99)

l <- as.numeric(sample(1:99, 21))
```

How to remove each row where the value `$v` of the datatable `DT` is identical with a value of :
`DT$v == l[ i ]`

Comment: `DT[!(v %in% l)]`? Your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: @Roland comment is elegant and according to `data.table` package: if you want to define a not in function, you can look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831794/opposite-of-in).

Comment: thx both of u, solved!

Comment: There's also an anti-join `DT[!.(l), on="v"]`