# subsetting data set by selecting data which does not match

Tags: r, subset, data-manipulation

I have the code

```
ISL2N=subset(Grouptwo, Grouptwo$Initials %in% ISL$Initials)
```

Now I want to do subsetting of values in `Grouptwo`, where `Grouptwo$Initials` does not match `ISL$Initials`

Comment: Try `subset(Grouptwo, !(Grouptwo$Initials %in% ISL$Initials)`

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831794/opposite-of-in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a logical NOT operator(!) which gives the opposite value of the result.

Try this:

```
ISL2N=subset(Grouptwo, !(Grouptwo$Initials %in% ISL$Initials))
```