# How to select the remaining values after creating a selection?

Tags: r

I have a group of values called "estados" (the States from USA), and I'm creating a selection of them which I'll call "pena_si" (each number is a State)

```
pena_si<-estados[c(10,14,11,27,41,36,16,42,51,34,45,28,17,25,18,46,29,43,3,37,4,44,19,26,2,48,31,9,5)]
```

So, now I'd like to create a selection of the values that aren't in "pena_si" but nothing I try works, so I'd like to know how would you do it. I've tried things like:

```
estados[estados!==pena_si]
```

But, as I said, it doesn't work.

Comment: Try `estados[!estados  %in%  pena_si]` or `setdiff(estados, pena_si)`  if  all are `unique`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Opposite of %in%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831794/opposite-of-in)

Comment: `estados != pena_si` would be testing that these two vectors aren't equal to each other (`!==` isn't R syntax, works in javascript though), whereas you want to test that one doesn't contain the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `%in%` and negate (`!`)

```
estados[!estados %in% pena_si]
```

Or with `setdiff` if the values are `unique`

```
setdiff(estados, pena_si)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, beside the two proposed by @akrun, is by using `-which`:

```
estados[-which(estados %in% pena_si)]
```