# What's the meaning of this exclamatory sign (!) in R language?

Tags: r

I don't understand the use of exclamatory signs here.

```
x <- [!x %in% boxplot(x)$out]
```

Comment: `x` is **not** in `boxplot(x)$out`

Comment: `!` is for negation of the logical condition.

Comment: Just fyi you can search for help on pretty much all operators. `help("!")` or `?\`!\``.

Comment: Have a look at [Opposite of %in%: exclude rows with values specified in a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5831794/10488504)

Comment: Try the simple `! TRUE` , which returns `FALSE`. It can not get clearer than that

Answer (score 2):

`!` is nothing more than just a negation.

You should start from `%in%` if the example you gave is problematic for you.

```
vector1 <- c("a", "b")

vector2 <- c("c", "a")

vector1 %in% vector2 # for each element of vector1 do: is it in vector2?
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE
```

if you use `!` now, i.e. negate the output, you will get:

```
!vector1 %in% vector2
#> [1] FALSE  TRUE
```