# Opposite of " %in% " : Error : invalid argument type

Tags: r

Given this data set:

```
original_data = data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), a = c("a", "b", "c"), b = c("d", "e", "f"))
```

I was able to run the following code:

```
original_data[which(original_data$a %in% c("a", "b") ),]
```

Now, I am trying to run the "opposite" of this code, but nothing seems to be working:

```
  original_data[which(original_data$a !%in% c("a", "b") ),]

Error: unexpected '!' in "original_data[which(original_data$a !"

 original_data[which(original_data$a %in%! c("a", "b") ),]

Error in !c("a", "b") : invalid argument type
```

I even tried the answer suggested over here: [Opposite of %in%: exclude rows with values specified in a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831794/opposite-of-in-exclude-rows-with-values-specified-in-a-vector)

```
'%!in%' <- function(x,y)!('%in%'(x,y))

 original_data[which(original_data$a '%!in%' c("a", "b") ),]

Error: unexpected '!' in "original_data[which(original_data$a !"
```

But nothing is working.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: you do not need quotes `'%!in%'` when you use `x %!in% y`

Comment: original_data[which(original_data$a %!in% c("a", "b") ),]

Answer (score 2):

You're putting the `!` in the wrong place. It should be before `original_data`.

```
original_data[which(!original_data$a %in% c("a", "b") ),]
```

Alternatively, you can create a "not in" variable like so:

```
`%nin%` <- Negate(`%in%`)
```

You can then use it:

```
original_data[which(original_data$a %nin% c("a", "b") ),]
```

Answer (score 1):

Define

```
 `%notin%` <- Negate(`%in%`)
```

and then just use `%notin%`

```
original_data[which(original_data$a %notin% c("a", "b") ),]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried this but it still isnt working

Comment: `%notin%` <- Negate(`%in%`) ;
 original_data[which(original_data$a `%notin%` c("a", "b") ),]

Comment: Error: unexpected symbol in "original_data[which(original_data$a `%notin%`"

Comment: When you use it you don't need the  `  ` ! Just %notin%

Comment: `original_data[which(original_data$a %notin% c("a", "b") ),]`