# not in %!in% not working? Change after update?

Tags: r

on an old script, I had a line of code:

```
harris_residential_hmgpmatch <- subset(harris_residential_hmgpmatch, ID %!in% selecting_good$ID) #357
```

I need to rerun this script now, but the %!in% is no longer working:

```
Error in ID %!in% selecting_good$ID : could not find function "%!in%"
```

I have updated R since I initially wrote and ran this script - could that be the culprit, or am I missing something simple?

Comment: The "not in" operator is not included in base R. Many packages include a version of it though. Apparently in at least one of them it's called `%!in%`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64139714/2854608 . Or if you do not want to load the package just use `!(ID %in% selecting_good$ID)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can customize your function like this

```r
`%!in%` <- Negate(`%in%`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `!` operator to the entire argument:

```
harris_residential_hmgpmatch <- subset(harris_residential_hmgpmatch, !(ID %!in% selecting_good$ID))
```