# How do I improve this syntax for creating a subset with factors?

Tags: r, subset, long-format-data

EDIT: A moderator has flagged this this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831794/opposite-of-in-exclude-rows-with-values-specified-in-a-vector) as very similar to mine. As a neophyte, I do not see these as similar. This reflects the discrepancy between my understanding of R and the moderator's. They see the obvious connection because they are experts. I do not, as I am still learning R. I suspect that other neophytes might benefit from my question as it is given: even if trivial, it is explicitly framed.

I am attempting to subset my data.table in long format, named `tmp`:

```
tmp <- structure(list(Year = c(1971, 1976, 1981, 1986, 1991, 1996, 2001, 
2006, 2011, 2016, 2021, 1971, 1976, 1981, 1986, 1991, 1996, 2001, 
2006, 2011, 2016, 2021, 1971, 1976, 1981, 1986, 1991, 1996, 2001, 
2006, 2011, 2016, 2021, 1971, 1976, 1981, 1986, 1991, 1996, 2001, 
2006, 2011, 2016, 2021, 1971, 1976, 1981, 1986, 1991, 1996, 2001, 
2006, 2011, 2016, 2021, 1971, 1976, 1981, 1986, 1991, 1996, 2001, 
2006, 2011, 2016, 2021, 1971, 1976, 1981, 1986, 1991, 1996, 2001, 
2006, 2011, 2016, 2021, 1971, 1976, 1981, 1986, 1991, 1996, 2001, 
2006, 2011, 2016, 2021, 1971, 1976, 1981, 1986, 1991, 1996, 2001, 
2006, 2011, 2016, 2021, 1971, 1976, 1981, 1986, 1991, 1996, 2001, 
2006, 2011, 2016, 2021, 1971, 1976, 1981, 1986, 1991, 1996, 2001, 
2006, 2011, 2016, 2021, 1971, 1976, 1981, 1986, 1991, 1996, 2001, 
2006, 2011, 2016, 2021), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), .Label = c("FORT ERIE", "GRIMSBY", 
"LINCOLN", "NIAGARA FALLS", "NIAGARA-ON-THE-LAKE", "PELHAM", 
"PORT COLBORNE", "ST. CATHARINES", "THOROLD", "WAINFLEET", "WELLAND", 
"WEST LINCOLN"), class = "factor"), value = c(23113L, 24030L, 
24096L, 23253L, 26006L, 27183L, 28143L, 29925L, 29960L, 30710L, 
32901L, 15770L, 15565L, 15797L, 16956L, 18520L, 19585L, 21297L, 
23937L, 25325L, 27314L, 28883L, 14247L, 14460L, 14196L, 14391L, 
17149L, 18801L, 20612L, 21722L, 22487L, 23787L, 25719L, 67163L, 
69420L, 70960L, 72107L, 75399L, 76917L, 78815L, 82184L, 82997L, 
88071L, 94415L, 12552L, 12485L, 12186L, 12494L, 12945L, 13238L, 
13839L, 14587L, 15400L, 17511L, 19090L, 9997L, 10070L, 11104L, 
12137L, 13328L, 14343L, 15272L, 16155L, 16598L, 17110L, 18192L, 
21420L, 20535L, 19225L, 18281L, 18766L, 18451L, 18450L, 18599L, 
18424L, 18306L, 20033L, 109722L, 123350L, 124018L, 123455L, 129300L, 
130926L, 129170L, 131989L, 131400L, 133113L, 136803L, 15065L, 
14945L, 15412L, 16131L, 17542L, 17883L, 18048L, 18224L, 17931L, 
18801L, 23816L, 5486L, 6065L, 6000L, 5955L, 6203L, 6253L, 6258L, 
6601L, 6356L, 6372L, 6887L, 44397L, 45050L, 45448L, 45054L, 47914L, 
48411L, 48402L, 50331L, 50631L, 52293L, 55750L, 8396L, 9460L, 
9846L, 9918L, 10864L, 11513L, 12268L, 13167L, 13837L, 14500L, 
15454L)), row.names = c(NA, -132L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
)
```

This data.table contains 132 rows and three columns: Year, variable and value. Year is the year data were collected. Variable is the name of the location. Value is the total population. There are 11 rows per location.

I wish to create a subset that excludes the value for NIAGARA FALLS, ST. CATHARINES and WELLAND.
This works:

```
tmpsmall9 <- subset(tmp, variable != 'NIAGARA FALLS') # subset excludes NF
tmpsmall9 <- subset(tmpsmall9, variable != 'ST. CATHARINES') # subset excludes ST. KITTY
tmpsmall9 <- subset(tmpsmall9, variable != "WELLAND") # subset excludes Welland
View(tmpsmall9)
```

This iterative solution eliminates 33 observations (i.e., rows) associated with those three factors in `variable` (i.e., Niagara Falls, St. Catharines, Welland), leaving 99 rows. However, I thought there must be a more efficient solution. So, I tried this:

```
tmpsmall9 <- subset(tmp, variable != c('NIAGARA FALLS','ST. CATHARINES','WELLAND'))
View(tmpsmall9)
```

This does not perform as expected. It leaves 121 rows. Niagara Falls still has 7 rows, St. Catharines 8, and Welland 7. The other factors (i.e., `variable`) have all their rows.

What is a more efficient and accurate way to subset factors than my iterative solution? Can my second solution be revised to work? (If not, can someone explain why this second `subset()` syntax only removes *some* of the observations for those three factors, and not all of them? Is it that logical operators can only handle one factor at a time?)

Comment: Marking a question as a duplicate doesn't destroy your question or infer that you've done anything wrong. It creates a connection between the way this question has been expressed and a previous question/answer which has been expressed differently, but covers the same ground. Hopefully that is a net benefit to future new users that come across the same issue.

Comment: Some further explanation as to why it's a duplicate: that question is about subsetting a dataset by excluding a list of values, which is what you want. Your `variable != c('NIAGARA FALLS','ST. CATHARINES','WELLAND')` searched for values != the list "NIAGARA FALLS"  "ST. CATHARINES" "WELLAND" and not the values separately. By using `%in%` it searches for each list value separately. As the answer from @jared_mamrot shows, you can negate/reverse the `%in%` search criteria by placing your code inside `!()` e.g. `!(variable %in% c('NIAGARA FALLS','ST. CATHARINES','WELLAND'))`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @JeffBoggs, sorry for the delayed reply. The link between your question and the duplicate is clear: the key words "exclude rows with values specified in a vector" is the same as your goal "create a subset that excludes the value for NIAGARA FALLS, ST. CATHARINES and WELLAND". The different wording in the title of the 'original' is more likely to be found by other users using a search engine, and my answer below is essentially showing you how to apply an answer from the original question. Closing a question doesn't delete it, it just redirects those who find their way here to the original

Comment: The redirection is important, as there are many answers to the original question and the answer I posted here might not be the best solution for other users. Closing a question as a duplicate is not a judgement on the quality of your question (which is great), but rather an attempt to keep answers in one place and make them easier to find for beginners and more advanced users alike; please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates for more details, or feel free to ask for further clarification. (also, I'm not a mod, just a user/contributor to the site with enough rep points to close q's)

Comment: Hi @jared_mamrot,(and thelatemail and Leroy Tyrone): Thanks for the kind words, and  taking the time to explain [a] why this is a duplicate, [b]  the difference between closing a question and deleting, and [c] and the redirection logic. That was very helpful and much appreciated.

Comment: Can someone explain why this attempt --- tmpsmall9 <- subset(tmp, variable != c('NIAGARA FALLS','ST. CATHARINES','WELLAND'))  --- only removes *some* of the rows  containing NIAGARA FALLS, ST. CATHARINES and WELLAND? And why there are 8 rows containing ST. CATHARINES and 7 rows each containing NIAGARA FALLS and WELLAND? I'm trying to understand the underlying logic at work. Intuitively, it would make more sense to me that if each would have the same number of rows just because that would be symmetrical (for lack of better words).

Comment: Without running your code, you generally don't compare one variable to another directly if you want to know if one vector has values also found in the other. `x != y` compares two vectors element-wise. `x %in% y` checks whether each value of `x` exists within `y`.  That's the syntax discussed in the other post

Comment: FYI: Your question was not flagged by a moderator, it was closed by a normal user with a lot of reputation in [tag:r], which allows them to single-handedly close questions that they consider duplicates. Moderators have a blue diamond next to their name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to negate the `%in%` operator, e.g.

```r
library(data.table)

tmp <- structure(list(Year = c(1971, 1976, 1981, 1986, 1991, 1996, 2001, 
                               2006, 2011, 2016, 2021, 1971, 1976, 1981, 1986, 1991, 1996, 2001, 
                               2006, 2011, 2016, 2021, 1971, 1976, 1981, 1986, 1991, 1996, 2001, 
                               2006, 2011, 2016, 2021, 1971, 1976, 1981, 1986, 1991, 1996, 2001, 
                               2006, 2011, 2016, 2021, 1971, 1976, 1981, 1986, 1991, 1996, 2001, 
                               2006, 2011, 2016, 2021, 1971, 1976, 1981, 1986, 1991, 1996, 2001, 
                               2006, 2011, 2016, 2021, 1971, 1976, 1981, 1986, 1991, 1996, 2001, 
                               2006, 2011, 2016, 2021, 1971, 1976, 1981, 1986, 1991, 1996, 2001, 
                               2006, 2011, 2016, 2021, 1971, 1976, 1981, 1986, 1991, 1996, 2001, 
                               2006, 2011, 2016, 2021, 1971, 1976, 1981, 1986, 1991, 1996, 2001, 
                               2006, 2011, 2016, 2021, 1971, 1976, 1981, 1986, 1991, 1996, 2001, 
                               2006, 2011, 2016, 2021, 1971, 1976, 1981, 1986, 1991, 1996, 2001, 
                               2006, 2011, 2016, 2021), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                               2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                                                               4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
                                                                               5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 
                                                                               7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
                                                                               8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
                                                                               10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
                                                                               11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
                                                                               12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), .Label = c("FORT ERIE", "GRIMSBY", 
                                                                                                                         "LINCOLN", "NIAGARA FALLS", "NIAGARA-ON-THE-LAKE", "PELHAM", 
                                                                                                                         "PORT COLBORNE", "ST. CATHARINES", "THOROLD", "WAINFLEET", "WELLAND", 
                                                                                                                         "WEST LINCOLN"), class = "factor"), value = c(23113L, 24030L, 
                                                                                                                                                                       24096L, 23253L, 26006L, 27183L, 28143L, 29925L, 29960L, 30710L, 
                                                                                                                                                                       32901L, 15770L, 15565L, 15797L, 16956L, 18520L, 19585L, 21297L, 
                                                                                                                                                                       23937L, 25325L, 27314L, 28883L, 14247L, 14460L, 14196L, 14391L, 
                                                                                                                                                                       17149L, 18801L, 20612L, 21722L, 22487L, 23787L, 25719L, 67163L, 
                                                                                                                                                                       69420L, 70960L, 72107L, 75399L, 76917L, 78815L, 82184L, 82997L, 
                                                                                                                                                                       88071L, 94415L, 12552L, 12485L, 12186L, 12494L, 12945L, 13238L, 
                                                                                                                                                                       13839L, 14587L, 15400L, 17511L, 19090L, 9997L, 10070L, 11104L, 
                                                                                                                                                                       12137L, 13328L, 14343L, 15272L, 16155L, 16598L, 17110L, 18192L, 
                                                                                                                                                                       21420L, 20535L, 19225L, 18281L, 18766L, 18451L, 18450L, 18599L, 
                                                                                                                                                                       18424L, 18306L, 20033L, 109722L, 123350L, 124018L, 123455L, 129300L, 
                                                                                                                                                                       130926L, 129170L, 131989L, 131400L, 133113L, 136803L, 15065L, 
                                                                                                                                                                       14945L, 15412L, 16131L, 17542L, 17883L, 18048L, 18224L, 17931L, 
                                                                                                                                                                       18801L, 23816L, 5486L, 6065L, 6000L, 5955L, 6203L, 6253L, 6258L, 
                                                                                                                                                                       6601L, 6356L, 6372L, 6887L, 44397L, 45050L, 45448L, 45054L, 47914L, 
                                                                                                                                                                       48411L, 48402L, 50331L, 50631L, 52293L, 55750L, 8396L, 9460L, 
                                                                                                                                                                       9846L, 9918L, 10864L, 11513L, 12268L, 13167L, 13837L, 14500L, 
                                                                                                                                                                       15454L)), row.names = c(NA, -132L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

tmpsmall9 <- subset(tmp, variable != 'NIAGARA FALLS') # subset excludes NF
tmpsmall9 <- subset(tmpsmall9, variable != 'ST. CATHARINES') # subset excludes ST. KITTY
tmpsmall9 <- subset(tmpsmall9, variable != "WELLAND") # subset excludes Welland

tmpsmall9_ver2 <- tmp[!(variable %in% c('NIAGARA FALLS','ST. CATHARINES','WELLAND'))]
all.equal(tmpsmall9, tmpsmall9_ver2)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for that working solution and the check using all.equal().