# How I can select rows from a dataframe that do not match BUT group by id?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to identify the values in a data frame that do not match based on id, but can't figure out how to do this.

```
a_id <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
a_no <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
a <- data.frame(a_id,a_no)
b_id <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3)
b_no <- c(1,2,3,1,3,2,3)
b <- data.frame(b_id,b_no)
```

Looking for dataframe similar to this

```
output_id <- c(2,3)
output_no <- c(2,1)
output <- data.frame(output_id,output_no)
```

I've tried to adjust the code here, but no luck: [How I can select rows from a dataframe that do not match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812478/how-i-can-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-that-do-not-match)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `anti_join`

```
library(dplyr)
anti_join(a, b, by = c("a_id" = "b_id", "a_no" = "b_no"))
#    a_id a_no
#1    2    2
#2    3    1
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(a)[!b, on = .(a_id = b_id, a_no = b_no)]
```